# having troubles installing laravel collective with composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"

Tags: laravel-5

after running `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"` in my vs code git bash it gives me the following errors:

> $ composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
>   which: no php in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cmd:/c/composer:/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/php.exe:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/c/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.38:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/matildah mariwa/AppData/Roaming/npm)
>   /c/composer/composer: line 10: php: command not found

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: am using 5.4.36

Answer (score 0):

Try this command for laravel 5.4

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4"
```

This may solve your issue.

if the issue is still there, then there is a problem with your PHP/Laravel system configuration.

Comment: Thanks.was using wamp changed to xampp forgot to update path

Comment: Please accept the answer and also upvote if the answer was helpful.